# Как удалить символы от начала строки до определенного символа?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, qregularexpression

Как удалить символы от начала строки до определенного символа на PHP?
Чтобы от подобных: `83-smartfony`, `59-planshety`, `94-noutbuki` осталось только `smartfony`, `noutbuki`, `planshety`.
Пытался через `str_replace('^(.*)/(\d+)-', '', $word);`, не получилось.

Comment: `str_replace` не поддерживает регулярные выражения. Используйте `preg_replace`. Например, если надо удалить всё до первой буквы, можно использовать `preg_replace('~^\P{L}+~u', '', $string)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew получилось, благодарю, понял в чем ошибка. Оформите как ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php) не поддерживает регулярные выражения в качастве аргумента `$search`. Используйте [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace).

Если надо удалить всё до первой буквы, можно использовать

```php
$string = preg_replace('~^\P{L}+~u', '', $string);
```

Тут `^\P{L}+` находит начало строки (`^`) и затем одну и более (`+`) символов, отличных от букв (`\P{L}`).

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/mYXIav/1).

См. [пример кода на PHP](https://3v4l.org/BCbeY):

```
$strs= ["83-smartfony","59-planshety","94-noutbuki"];
foreach ($strs as $string){
    echo preg_replace('~^\P{L}+~u', '', $string) . PHP_EOL;
}
// => smartfony
//    planshety
//    noutbuki
```

Если нужно удалить цифры и знак дефиса в начале строки, используйте

```php
$string = preg_replace('~^\d+-~', '', $string);
```

См. [пример работы этого регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/mYXIav/2).

Answer (score 1):

Если есть символ разделитель, то лучше использовать вызов функции `explode`

```php
print_r(explode('-','55-fsfsdgs',2));
```

Вернет

```txt
Array
(
    [0] => 55
    [1] => fsfsdgs
)
```

Более подробно можно прочитать тут: [www.php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

Comment: Спасибо, изначально хотел воспользоваться подобным решением, но внутри "полезной" части, которая после цифр, иногда тоже встречаются "-"

Comment: @QuickBrownFox, как раз в данной конструкции команда будет работать именно так, как вы и хотите, если передать строку типа `55-fsfsdgs-33-dfdfsw` то массив запишется так: `Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => fsfsdgs-33-dfdfsw )`. В самой функции 3 параметр отвечает за количество частей разделения.